# multiple string search with failed_when in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

Team, 
somehow not able to figure out what error is this.. I am doing a multiple string search and failing accordingly for each string not found.

```
      - name: "Validate kubectl access and k8s node lables"
        debug:
          msg: "kubectl get nodes --show-labels -l nodeType={{item}}"
        with_items:
          - gpu
          - cpu
          - monitoring
        register: k8s_labelsresponse

      - debug:
          var: k8s_labelsresponse.stdout
        failed_when: '"nodeType=gpu" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or "nodeType=cpu" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or "nodeType=monitoring" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout'
```

output:

```
TASK [Validate kubectl access and k8s node lables] 
ok: [target1] => (item=gpu) => {
    "msg": "kubectl get nodes --show-labels -l nodeType=gpu"
}
ok: [target1] => (item=cpu) => {
    "msg": "kubectl get nodes --show-labels -l nodeType=cpu"
}
ok: [target1] => (item=monitoring) => {
    "msg": "kubectl get nodes --show-labels -l nodeType=monitoring"
}
```

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '\"nodeType=gpu\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or \"nodeType=cpu\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or \"nodeType=monitoring\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (\"nodeType=gpu\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or \"nodeType=cpu\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or \"nodeType=monitoring\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if \"nodeType=gpu\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or \"nodeType=cpu\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout or \"nodeType=monitoring\" not in k8s_labelsresponse.stdout %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'AnsibleUndefined' is not iterable"}
```

Comment: Take a look at the variable `debug: var=k8s_labelsresponse` to see what might be tested.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your variable `k8s_labelsresponse` is a map so u don't have `stdout`. Take a look by `debug: var=k8s_labelsresponse`
You could make that variable by:

```
      msg:
        - kubectl get nodes --show-labels -l nodeType=gpu
        - kubectl get nodes --show-labels -l nodeType=cpu
        - kubectl get nodes --show-labels -l nodeType=monitoring
```

But this solution is very ugly because its hardcode.
I recommend creating a dynamic variable with the help of Jinja2 and set_fact:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    params:
      - cpu
      - gpu
      - monitoring
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      k8s_labelsresponse: "{% for param in params -%}
        nodeType={{ param }}

        {% endfor %}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ k8s_labelsresponse.splitlines() }}"
    failed_when:  '"nodeType=gpu" not in k8s_labelsresponse  or "nodeType=cpu" not in k8s_labelsresponse or "nodeType=monitoring" not in k8s_labelsresponse'
```